# Which is the best way to represent the business opening hours in a Java object?

Tags: java

I need to represent opening hours, and a method which returns true/false for a certain day and time.
Is there any package which has this functionality already?

Edit: Basically I would need to construct an object with data out of db or a file, then perform a basic check against the object, like if it's closed at a certain moment.

The problem was that some businesses will have working hours after 00:00 so it overlaps the next day.
In this case I figure out that the object should be able to support multiple time frames per day, also to cover lunch brakes.

Comment: It is impossible for any package to meet your *stated* requirement because it is so vague. Essentially, business hours are determined by a set of "business rules". What kinds of business rules are you interested in?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a class by using `Calendar` and see if its working day and working hour now.

```
class BusinessHour{

public void isOpenNow(){
  Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    //check the rules for example , if day is MOn-FRi and time is 9-18.
  }
}
```

I don't think there would be a ready made because each business has its own specification, You could probably make if configurable so that it fixes for all the business, provide the conf parameter externally to the class for better design

Answer (score 5):

I use following Object to store OpeningHours in HashSet. Example bellow can be easily simplified using seconds from Midnight instead of "800" or "1600" for hours but I like it this way.

```
public class OpeningHours {
  public enum DAY {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
  }

public OpeningHours(DAY day, Integer from, Integer to) {
    this.day = day;
    this.from = from; // format time using 800 for 8:00am or 2300 for 23:00
    this.to = to;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "OpeningHours [day=" + day + ", from=" + from + ", to=" + to + ", isAllDay=" + isAllDay + "]";
}

public OpeningHours() {

}

public DAY day;
public Integer from;
public Integer to;
public boolean isAllDay = false;

public void isOpenx(DateTime start) {

}

public boolean isOpen(DateTime start) {

    if (day.ordinal() != start.getDayOfWeek() - 1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (isAllDay)
        return true;

    String f = String.format("%04d", from);
    String t = String.format("%04d", to);

    Integer fh = Integer.valueOf(f.substring(0, 2));
    Integer fm = Integer.valueOf(f.substring(2));

    Integer th = Integer.valueOf(t.substring(0, 2));
    Integer tm = Integer.valueOf(t.substring(2));

    DateTime intStart = start.withHourOfDay(fh).withMinuteOfHour(fm);
    DateTime intEnd = start.withHourOfDay(th).withMinuteOfHour(tm);

    if (intStart.equals(start) || intEnd.equals(start)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (intStart.isBefore(start) && intEnd.isAfter(start)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
}
```

```
HashSet<OpeningHours> hours = new HashSet<OpeningHours>();
hours.add(new OpeningHours(OpeningHours.DAY.MONDAY, 800, 1200));
hours.add(new OpeningHours(OpeningHours.DAY.MONDAY, 1230, 1600));


DateTime dateToCheck = new DateTime(2012, 9, 4, 8, 00, 0, 0);

for (OpeningHours item : hours) {
  boolean isOpen = item.isOpen(dateToCheck );
  if (isOpen){
    System.out.println("Is Open!");
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you deal with `open from 20:00 til 06:00`?

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8, you can represent it as a set of openingTimes objects:

The set:

```
 Set<OpeningTimes> openingTimes = new HashSet<>();
```

OpeningTimes

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class OpeningTimes {
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
    private LocalTime from;
    private LocalTime to;

    public DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    public void setDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    public LocalTime getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(LocalTime from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public LocalTime getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(LocalTime to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not account for days when the subject is not open at all.

Answer (score 2):

There probably isn't a package that already implement your exact business logic.

For example, do you need to override the standard opening days on certain days of the year, e.g. closures for special events? What about public holidays, do you open for these?

My simple suggested solution would be:

1. Create a database table with (day, opening time, closing time) as fields
2. Create a function that take a day and time as parameters, and
   looks up in the database table to see if is within the
   opening/closing times for  given day
3. Provide an easy way for
   business users to update the open/closing times after pre-populating
   them with your standard times

Answer (score 0):

The following class also takes into account the case when a thing (e.g. a building) is not open at all on the specified day.

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * {@code OpeningHours} represents the opening hours of a single day of a "thing"
 * (e.g. a building). The opening- and closing hour are independent of timezones.
 */
public class OpeningHours {
    private boolean opensToday;
    private LocalTime openingHour;
    private LocalTime closingHour;

    /**
     * A reusable {@code OpeningHours} that is always closed.
     */
    private static OpeningHours closedInstance = new OpeningHours();

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@code OpeningHours} for a thing that does not open at this specific day.
     */
    public OpeningHours() {
        opensToday = false;
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@code OpeningHours} for a thing that does open today.
     *
     * @param openingHour the opening hour of the thing, inclusive. Must be strictly less than the closingHour
     * @param closingHour the closing hour of the thing, exclusive. Must be strictly more than the openingHour
     */
    public OpeningHours(@NotNull LocalTime openingHour, @NotNull LocalTime closingHour) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(openingHour);
        Objects.requireNonNull(closingHour);

        if (openingHour.compareTo(closingHour) >= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the openingHour must be strictly less than the closingHour");

        this.opensToday = true;
        this.openingHour = openingHour;
        this.closingHour = closingHour;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the thing this {@code OpeningHours} belongs to will open today.
     *
     * @return the value of {@link #opensToday}
     */
    public boolean opensToday() {
        return opensToday;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the provided {@code time} is within the opening hours. More specifically this method returns
     * {@code true} when {@code time} is equal to or greater than {@code this#getOpeningHour()} and strictly less
     * than {@code this.getClosingHour()}.
     *
     * @param time the time at wh
     * @return {@code true} if {@code time} is greater than or equal to {@link #openingHour} and strictly less than
     *         {@link #closingHour}.
     */
    public boolean isOpen(LocalTime time) {
        if (!opensToday)
            return false;
        return (openingHour.compareTo(time) <= 0) && (closingHour.compareTo(time) > 0) ;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the current time is within the opening hours.
     * 
     * @see #isOpen(LocalTime)
     */
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return this.isOpen(LocalTime.now());
    }


    /**
     * @return an {@code OpeningHours} for a thing that is permanently closed on this day.
     */
    public OpeningHours getClosedInstance() {
        return closedInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        OpeningHours that = (OpeningHours) o;

        if (opensToday != that.opensToday) return false;
        if (!Objects.equals(openingHour, that.openingHour)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(closingHour, that.closingHour);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (opensToday ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (openingHour != null ? openingHour.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (closingHour != null ? closingHour.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OpeningHours{" +
                "opensToday=" + opensToday +
                ", openingHour=" + openingHour +
                ", closingHour=" + closingHour +
                '}';
    }
}
```